# Cannot reduce size of gtk window programatically

Tags: c, resize, window, gtk, gtk2

I seem to be facing a problem when resizing a gtk window programatically. The problem is that once I have increased the width and height of the window to 800x600, I cannot seem to reduce it back to its original size of 400x200.
Below is the sample code. Has anyone faced such a problem?

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static gboolean is_clicked = FALSE;

static void Child_window_resize( GtkWidget *widget,
               GtkWidget *window)
{
    if(!is_clicked)
    {
        g_print("Inside If block increase bool value %d\n",is_clicked);
        gtk_widget_set_size_request(window,800,600);
        is_clicked = TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        g_print("Inside Else block decrease bool value %d\n",is_clicked);
        gtk_widget_set_size_request(window,400,200);
        is_clicked = FALSE;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *fixed;
    GtkWidget *resizebutton;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(window,400,200);
    gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(window),TRUE);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Demo Resize");
    gtk_window_set_decorated(GTK_WINDOW(window),FALSE);
    gtk_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
                        GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(gtk_exit), NULL);

    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 10);
    // creating a fixed GTK_CONTAINER
    fixed = gtk_fixed_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),fixed);
    gtk_widget_show(fixed);

    resizebutton = gtk_button_new_with_label("Resize");
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(resizebutton, 80, 60);
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), resizebutton, 0, 0);

    gtk_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(resizebutton), "clicked",
                GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(Child_window_resize), window);

    gtk_widget_show(resizebutton);
    gtk_widget_show(window);
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

Complied using ...

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -g resize.c -o resize -export-dynamic `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0 gthread-2.0`
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `gtk_widget_set_size_request()`, you need [`gtk_window_resize()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-resize).

From the linked manual:

> ```
> void
> gtk_window_resize (GtkWindow *window,
>                    gint width,
>                    gint height);
> ```
>
> Resizes the window as if the user had done so, obeying geometry
>   constraints. The default geometry constraint is that windows may not
>   be smaller than their size request; to override this constraint, call
>   `gtk_widget_set_size_request()` to set the window's request to a smaller
>   value.
>
> If `gtk_window_resize()` is called before showing a window for the first
>   time, it overrides any default size set with
>   `gtk_window_set_default_size()`.
>
> Windows may not be resized smaller than 1 by 1 pixels.